# Why does the =SUM() function not work with numbers transmitted by query in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Why does the =SUM() function not work with numbers transmitted by query in Google Sheet

Comment: change the 1 at the end of your querys to a 0.

Comment: @MattKing this can be a good legitimate answer for this question. You may want to post this as an answer.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the 1 at the end of your querys to a 0.

However, the way you've written those formulas is not a very efficient way to get the values you want and may slow down your sheet quite a bit if used at scale.

Comment: I've tried change the 1 at the end of your querys to a 0 . It works I am grateful for your answer-MR.-MattKing